# Two different variables with same identity in the same object with inheritance in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, member

I am trying to learn about inheritance i Java and get confused by this example as there seem to exist two different speedlimit variables in the same instance of the object. One from the super class and one from the sub class. Still there is only one object, a Honda3 object (referenced by a bike reference).What is the reason for this? Are there two different instance variables?

```
class Bike
{  
   int speedlimit=92; 
   public void showSpeedLimit()
   {   System.out.println("From Bike: SL= "+ this.speedlimit); }
       public void SetSpeedLimit(int limit) 
   {  this.speedlimit=limit;}
}  
class Honda3 extends Bike
{  
   int speedlimit=150;  
   public void showSpeedLimit()
   {   System.out.println("From Honda3: SL= "+ this.speedlimit); }
   public void SetSpeedLimit(int limit)
   { this.speedlimit=limit; }
}
public class main2 
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {  
      Bike obj;//reference to Bike object
      obj=new Honda3();// Honda3 object created and assigned to the reference variable named obj 
      System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);//90 Data member not overridden
      obj.showSpeedLimit();//150 showing Honda3;
      obj.speedlimit+=3;//95 Bike
      System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);//95
      obj.showSpeedLimit();//still 150
      obj.SetSpeedLimit(155);// setting Honda3 object speedlimit to 155
      System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);// still 95
      obj.showSpeedLimit();//155
   } 
}
```

**Output:**

92
 From Honda3: SL= 150,
 95,
 From Honda3: SL= 150,
 95,
 From Honda3: SL= 155**

Comment: `int speedlimit=150;` declared a second member variable for the class `Honda3`

Comment: *Are there two different instance variables?*: yes: one in the base class, and one in the subclass: `int speedlimit=92;` and `int speedlimit=150;`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Java doesn't override variables. This is the reason whenever you try to print obj.speedlimit it prints the value of parent as it is the reference of Bike.
2. When you call the `showSpeedlimit` method it works as expected because that method is overridden.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you can override the method of Parent Class in Child Class. This is call method overriding. You cannot override the attribute of a class. In your case, you have 2 instance variable one from base class and another from Parent class. Only one Object is created.

```
       Bike obj;//reference to Bike object
        obj=new Honda3();// Honda3 object created and assigned to the reference variable named obj 
        System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);//90 Base class attribute value is printed

    obj.speedlimit+=3;//95 Bike Base Class attribute value is updated
          System.out.println(obj.speedlimit);//95

obj.SetSpeedLimit(155);// Child class attribute value is updated speedlimit to 155
```

Comment: @Grandalfion Please accept the answer if it resolves your issue.